# Employee stock options - where do the shares come from?

Tags: employee-stock-options, compensation

Employee stock options are commonly offered by employers as part of compensation.
I understand that they basically mean "You (employee) can buy X shares at time Y for a price of P." If the price of the shares (say P2) is greater than P at the point the option vests, the employee has a fincancial gain of P2-P per share.

So far, so good. However: **Where do these shares come from?** Does the employer buy them at market price, and pass them on to the employee, while eating the loss (P2-P)? Or will the employer issue additional shares? Are they allowed to do this without shareholder approval (as this dilutes ownership)? Also, what if the company is not (yet) publicly traded? Does that make a difference?

Comment: A company usually retains some number of shares for itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the company is public, the board of directors will authorize a stock plan to issue a certain number of new shares, and the shareholders vote to approve (or reject) the proposal.

If the company is private, the board will typically authorize a stock plan. In my experience, common shareholders (employees) don't vote to approve or reject the plan, and that may be because the preferred shareholders (investors) have voting rights (sometimes a multiple like 10x votes per share owned) that vastly outweigh the power of common shareholders. That differs from public companies, where preferred shareholders don't have voting rights. The preferred shareholders, in this case, would be the ones approving or rejecting the board's proposal.

Stock plans allow companies to issue new shares to employees, and sometimes shares are given back to the company which adds to a company's "treasury stock" (essentially previously-issued but currently unused shares). Treasury stock might be able to be used for equity grants, depending on the company's rules on what the treasury stock can be used for.

Comment: As an ordinary stockholder. I have voted  on motions to repurchase shares to be issued to employees at a discount through the ESPP. I have generally voted in favor of this as an investment in employee motivation and thus a reasonable use of the company's money. I'm sure others have voted against, but generally the stockholders do approve this if it is at all reasonable.